# javascriptで一致するデータが存在したら削除したい

Tags: javascript

```
[{
  id: 1,
  data: "hoge"
},{
  id: 3,
  data: "hogehogehoge"
},{
  id: 4,
  data: "fugafuga"
}];
```

このようなデータがあった場合に、例えば`id: 3`のデータは削除するといったようなことは可能でしょうか。

```
a = [{
  id: 1,
  data: "hoge"
},{
  id: 3,
  data: "hogehogehoge"
},{
  id: 4,
  data: "fugafuga"
}];


a.removeDataById(3)

↓結果
a = [{
  id: 1,
  data: "hoge"
},{
  id: 4,
  data: "fugafuga"
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function removeById(array, id) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array[i].id == id)
      array.splice(i, 1)
  }
}
```

ループの方向にご注意。

Comment: ループ中にarrayの要素数が減少しますから、複数要素が該当する場合、および範囲外の末尾アクセスを考えればループの方向はカウントダウンが適切です。

Answer (score 2):

非標準ですが `Array.prototype.filter` を使うという手もあります。
Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9以上 で対応している様です。
`Array.prototype.filter` の polyfill は [Array.prototype.filter() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) に載っています。

```js
var a = [{
  id: 1,
  data: "hoge"
}, {
  id: 3,
  data: "hogehogehoge"
}, {
  id: 4,
  data: "fugafuga"
}];

// filter の引数: 残したい要素で true を返す関数を指定
var b = a.filter(function(entry){return entry.id!=3;});

// ※a 自体が変更されるのではなく新しい配列 b が生成される事に注意
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(b);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.prototype.removeById(id) {
  for (var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (this[i].id == id)
      this.splice(i, 1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

また[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)でのソリューションを提案したいと思います。

```js
function removeById(array, id) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (array[i].id === id) {
      array.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

var array = [{
  id: 1,
  data: "hoge"
}, {
  id: 3,
  data: "hogehogehoge"
}, {
  id: 4,
  data: "fugafuga"
}];

removeById(array, 3);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers